# how to create a web gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I've been searching for a way to implement a gallery in my first ever website (written in HTML).
I basically want to make a page with thumbnails, and, when clicking the thumbnail, a bigger picture to show up (over the gallery, not exiting the gallery), eventually with a title under it, and , when clicking the big picture, to return to the gallery (eventually with a fading effect)
The problem is that I don't even know what I should be looking for, exactly, in this case.

Comment: Try out bootstrap framework. This has everything you want.

Comment: If you want to learn, you should try doing a simple gallery, w/o effects, thumbnails, etc. Then you improve it. Is not recommended to use it on your web site, since that kind of presentation should work in many devices nowadays. For your website try a plugin instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to build the gallery from scratch, I recommend using one of the many libraries that you can find online.

Here's a list of some very useful JavaScript/jQuery photo galleries:

[Top 10 Free Responsive Image Galleries.](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/free-responsive-image-gallery/)

Hope it helps,
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries online that do exactly this. My first google search came up with the following [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/). Included in the webpage is a link to their documentation and git repo. If you would like other choices, [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/free-responsive-image-gallery/) website lists 10 libraries that do exactly what you want